# FFMPEG color overlay produces scrubbing/time navigation issue

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, overlay

I am trying to make a command that will blank video to a black screen for a specified period of time, to use in a video editing script. I have a version that will work with a black image file, but I am trying to do it with without needing the extra file. I have put together a version of the command that *mostly* works- using lavfi color generation, but presents an odd problem: whenever the video is fast forwarded, scrubbed, or otherwise time-navigated in a manner other than just watching it, the audio cuts out. The overlay *visually* works properly. If I just play the video from beginning to end, the audio works fine. The audio only cuts out if I try to jump around in the video in any manner.

I did play around with setpts for the video filtering a little, because I have a vague, uneducated feeling this is a timecode or a/v sync issue. I am not including what I tried with that because I have little confidence in the manner in which I tried it being correct. I am relatively new to ffmpeg and don't have a great understanding of the deeper workings of timecode or a/v stream sync.

Here is the image file version of my overlay command that doesn't produce this issue that I am currently using:

`ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -i "input.mkv" -i "overlay.jpg" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between(t,60,120)'[1V]" -map [1V] -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -c:s copy "output.mkv"`

Here is the lavfi color version of my overlay command that produces the issue that I want to get working:

`ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -i "input.mkv" -f lavfi -i "color=color=black:size=720x480:rate=(24000/1001)" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1:enable='between(t,60,120)'[1V]" -map [1V] -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -c:s copy "output.mkv"`

I am trying to avoid directly filtering the audio because I want the script to be able to handle a variable number of audio streams without having to account for them individually. If I do need to do something with my audio streams, could you please indicate an answer that can filter *all* the audio streams from the input video at once (if that's even possible).

This is my first post to a forum like this, so please forgive any mistakes in how these questions are normally posted. Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: What kind of media player do you use? I tested your both commands and I did not notice any audio problems with output videos played by VLC.

Comment: The issue is most likely related to your input file, so we can't reproduce it. You may try: `ffmpeg.exe -y -i input.mkv -filter_complex "color=black[b];[b][0:v]scale2ref[blk];[0:v][blk]overlay=shortest=1:enable='between(t,60,120)'[1V]" -map [1V] -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -c:s copy -max_interleave_delta 0 "output.mkv"`. The `-max_interleave_delta 0` is from [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28719/srt-subtitles-added-to-mkv-with-ffmpeg-are-not-displayed). I don't think it solves the issue. It is just more general solution (without setting `size` and `rate`).

Comment: I am using VLC to test these with, but have tried with other players and seen strange behavior there as well. Adding -max_interleave_delta 0 to my command 100% took care of the issue! I will have to do some digging to understand that element better. To both of your comments: I very well may have messed these files up with some pre-processing with ffmpeg, so I will do some testing to isolate if I'm messing something up elsewhere as well. Thank you for your help! Rotem, if you could post your reply as an answer, I will mark it answered.